# Can't get new Scrapy item exporter to work

Tags: python, scrapy

The following code was working for me but I learned the `FEED_FORMAT` and `FEED_URI` settings have been deprecated:

```
def _scrape_kenpom_rankings(year):
    settings = get_project_settings()
    settings.set('FEED_FORMAT', 'jsonlines')
    settings.set('FEED_URI', f'raw/kenpom_{year}.json')

    process = CrawlerProcess(settings)
    process.crawl(KenpomRankingsSpider, year)
    process.start()
```

So after reading the docs I learned the new way to do this is to add the `FEEDS` dict to the `custom_setting` inside my Spider:

```
custom_settings = {
    'AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED': True,
    'AUTOTHROTTLE_DEBUG': True,
    'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 1,
    'DEPTH_LIMIT': 1,
    'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_IP': 1,
    'FEEDS': {
        '/path/to/items.json': {
            'format': 'jsonlines',
            'encoding': 'utf8',
            'store_empty': False,
            'indent': 4,
            'overwrite': True
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately this is just not working. There is no output, whereas before, as I said with the now deprecated code it was working just fine. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why the other way doesn't work, but I did figure out a solution. Instead of defining `FEEDS` setting in the Spider, I set it in the `CrawlerProcess` and that works:

```
process = CrawlerProcess(settings={
        'FEEDS': {
            'file:///path/to/items.json': {
                'format': 'jsonlines',
                'overwrite': True
            }
        }
    })
process.crawl(Spider)
process.start()
```